# Why is there not a special exception for "Yes" and "No" in regards to minimum comment-lengths?

Tags: discussion

I always knew there was a minimum comment length, and it makes sense.

However, it would seem to me that "Yes" and "No" should be a special case.

Because - they are used simply to confirm .

Comment: Because . . . . .

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Yes

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Ha! if you have a long username, the "yes" fits in

Comment: I just see alot of cases where it could get annoying. `UserToddler: Does the fish go here wizard?` .... `Sage: .......yes`

Comment: YesFILLERFILLER

Answer (score 17):

No.

Comment: No............?

Comment: @Coffee - Nope.

Comment: No​​​​​​​​​​​​​​